# Hyperlink to force Excel to open in Excel Services

Tags: excel-services, office

We have found that a link, like the following, pasted into an Outlook email will always open the target file in the users *local* copy of Excel:

```
<http://ourspbi/myreports/Some Excel report 20Jan2014.xlsx>
```

Is there a type of hyperlink which can do the opposite - open the file in Excel Services rather than their local Excel ?

(We are using the Office edition immediately before 365 and Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise)

Comment: SharePoint 2012? You mean 2013? :)

Comment: check this one: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/using-hyperlinks-in-excel-services-HA010173679.aspx if you doing the same way.

Comment: @RobertLindgren - amended version (obviously I'm a little green when it comes to SP!)

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE - very nice link: would suffice as an answer with the specific section near the end of the article quoted - should I self-answer or would you like to?